# Can Microsoft InTune deploy a client certificate (.p12) cert to the 'User Certificates' > 'Personal' Store?

Tags: client-certificates, intune

Can Microsoft InTune deploy a client certificate (.p12) cert to the 'User Certificates' > 'Personal' Store?

I want to deploy a Client Certificate (.p12) to all end user devices via InTune.

I do not want to use SCEP or PKCS Profile Type, as then I require an On-Prem AD/CA/NDES/etc. and to install software on servers, all of which I'm trying to avoid. (Azure Only)

I believe my best option is to add a Powershell script to deploy the file locally..

Is is possible to do this without Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Intune only support to assign the following two certificates types to devices:

Simple Certificate Enrollment Protocol (SCEP)
PKCS#12 (or PFX)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/certificates-configure

Best regards,
Cici Wu